# immutable Map (de)serialization to/from Play JSON

Tags: json, serialization, dictionary, playframework, deserialization

I have following (simplified) structure:

```
case class MyKey(key: String)
case class MyValue(value: String)
```

Let's assume that I have Play JSON formatters for both case classes.

As an example I have:

```
val myNewMessage = collection.immutable.Map(MyKey("key1") -> MyValue("value1"), MyKey("key2") -> MyValue("value2"))
```

As a result of following transformation

```
play.api.libs.json.Json.toJson(myNewMessage)
```

I'm expecting something like:

```
{ "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2" }
```

I have tried writing the formatter, but somehow I can not succeed:

```
implicit lazy val mapMyKeyMyValueFormat: Format[collection.immutable.Map[MyKey, MyValue]] = new Format[collection.immutable.Map[MyKey, MyValue]] {
  override def writes(obj: collection.immutable.Map[MyKey, MyValue]): JsValue = Json.toJson(obj.map {
    case (key, value) ⇒ Json.toJson(key) -> Json.toJson(value)
  })

  override def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[collection.immutable.Map[MyKey, MyValue]] = ???
}
```

I have no idea how to write proper `reads` function. Is there any simpler way of doing it? I'm also not satisfied with my `writes` function.

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the `writes` method is not working is because you're transforming the `Map[MyKey, MyValue]` into a `Map[JsValue, JsValue]`, but you can't serialize that to JSON. The JSON keys need to be strings, so you need some way of transforming `MyKey` to some unique `String` value. Otherwise you'd be trying to serialize something like this:

```
{"key": "keyName"} : {"value": "myValue"}
```

Which is not valid JSON.

If `MyKey` is as simple as stated in your question, this can work:

```
def writes(obj: Map[MyKey, MyValue]): JsValue = Json.toJson(obj.map {
    case (key, value) => key.key -> Json.toJson(value)
})                     //   ^ must be a String
```

Play will then know how to serialize a `Map[String, MyValue]`, given the appropriate `Writes[MyValue]`.

But I'm not certain that's what you want. Because it produces this:

```
scala> Json.toJson(myNewMessage)
res0: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"key1":{"value":"value1"},"key2":{"value":"value2"}}
```

If this is the output you want:

```
{ "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2" }
```

Then your `Writes` should look more like this:

```
def writes(obj: Map[MyKey, MyValue]): JsValue = {
    obj.foldLeft(JsObject(Nil)) { case (js, (key, value)) =>
         js ++ Json.obj(key.key -> value.value)
    }
}
```

Which produces this:

```
scala> writes(myNewMessage)
res5: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}
```

`Reads` are easy so long as the structure of `MyKey` and `MyValue` are the same, otherwise I have no idea what you'd want it to do. It's very dependent on the actual structure you want. As is, I would suggest leveraging existing `Reads[Map[String, String]]` and transforming it to the type you want.

```
def reads(js: JsValue): JsResult[Map[MyKey, MyValue]] = {
    js.validate[Map[String, String]].map { case kvMap =>
        kvMap.map { case (key, value) => MyKey(key) -> MyValue(value) }
    }
}
```

It's hard to see much else without knowing the actual structure of the data. In general I stay away from having to serialize and deserialize `Map`s.